# utf8 in plot labels using knitr

Tags: r, plot, knitr

Can't compile the following Rnw document into pdf using knitr

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[russian]{babel}
\begin{document}

<<>>=
hist(rnorm(100),main="Гистограмма")
@

\end{document}
```

With labels in English everything is ok.

---

Edit 1:
Now i have two versions of pdf. In [the first one](https://github.com/bdemeshev/em301/raw/master/russian_labels_knitr/f.pdf) letters are replaced by points.

In [the second one](https://github.com/bdemeshev/em301/raw/master/russian_labels_knitr/ff.pdf) all letters are overlapped. The second one is produced using addtional code chunk

```
<<>>=
pdf.options(encoding = "CP1251")
@
```

I am using Ubuntu 12.04 + R 2.14 + Texlive.

---

Edit 2:

For the moment i've found the following partial solution:

```
<<>>=
cairo_pdf("figure.pdf")
hist(rnorm(100),main="Гистограмма")
dev.off()
@
\includegraphics{figure.pdf}
```

---

Edit 3:

Using the following code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[russian]{babel}
\begin{document}

<<dev='cairo_pdf'>>=
hist(rnorm(100),main="Гистограмма")
@

\end{document}
```

I obtain a CORRECT histogram, with a [lot of WARNINGS](https://github.com/bdemeshev/em301/raw/master/russian_labels_knitr/fff.pdf). How to avoid or at least suppress them?

---

Finally! Ura!

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[russian]{babel}
\begin{document}

<<dev='cairo_pdf',warning=FALSE>>=
hist(rnorm(100),main="Гистограмма")
@

\end{document}
```

Could i avoid warnings? Can someone explain me all that stuff with encodings and warnings?

Comment: What happens instead of pdf compilation? Do you get an error or does it simply hang?

Comment: Oh, the dreaded localization. I had a spat with it yesterday and I think I lost a significant portion of my hair.

Comment: sebastian-c, i have added two links to pdfs produced

Comment: you can simply use `<<dev='cairo_pdf'>>=` for the second solution; see http://yihui.name/en/2012/06/enjoyable-reproducible-research/

Comment: to suppress warnings, use the chunk option `warning=FALSE`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may need to set `pdf.options(encoding = 'your_encoding')`; see https://github.com/yihui/knitr/issues/172 I'm not entirely sure what exactly the encoding should be here.

Comment: i've tried `pdf.options(encoding = 'CP1251')`. it makes all letters overlapped.